# NSIS ExecWait dosen't wait when installing the setup file via chrome browser

Tags: installation, nsis

When downloading the .exe installation file (NSIS installation) and opening it via chrome in order to execute it the ExecWait dosen't work.

I'm running a batch file which kill browsers processes inside of the installation,
because I opened the exe file via the chrome (Download Manager) the ExecWait think that the execute has ended and therefore dosen't wait for the next ExecWait calls that coming after the line which call to execute the batch file. It think that chrome was the parent process so it quitting the installation.

Is there a way to let the ExecWait know that although I killed the chrome browser (or any other browsers) process to continue the installation? and waiting for only the .exe files that I execute via the NSIS script?

P.S - When installing the .exe file out of the browser (download manager) it works fine.

**EDIT (I HAVE INCLUDED CODES):**

```
# define the name of the installer
outfile "setup.exe"
Name "Example"

installDir $LOCALAPPDATA\Test

# default section
section

setOutPath $INSTDIR
File install.exe
File test.exe

ExecWait $INSTDIR\install.exe
Delete $INSTDIR\install.exe
ExecWait $INSTDIR\test.exe
Delete $INSTDIR\test.exe

sectionEnd
```

and inside of the install.exe (its a .bat file the I compile to an .exe file) this code:

```
@echo off
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T
```

If you download the setup.exe via chrome and executing it from the bottom bar (download manager) it will execute install.exe (closing chrome.exe) but will skip this lines:

```
Delete $INSTDIR\install.exe
ExecWait $INSTDIR\test.exe
Delete $INSTDIR\test.exe
```

Comment: Your symptoms are weird. Could you post some code showing the portion of nsis with the `ExecWait`?

Comment: I have included the nsis code and a description. thank you!

Comment: Why use a huge hack like renaming a batch file to .exe?

Comment: What if the user has another program also called chrome.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecWait **always** waits for the child process it started but it does not wait for grandchildren. If you need to do that you can try [this macro](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecWait_and_waiting_for_child_processes_with_Job_Objects).

IMHO killing a browser like this is not cool (What if they are doing something important in a tab?), you should just ask the user to close it.

Comment: Why is this grandchildren? the execwait live inside of the setup.exe right? isnt install.exe and test.exe are childs? so why execwait is connected to the chrome browser?  Yes install.exe and test.exe are grandchild processes but I don't get why is execwait connected in the way you mentioned..

Comment: When you use ExecWait $INSTDIR\install.exe it will only wait for install.exe and not things started by install.exe. Try replacing "taskkill ..." with "call taskkill..." or add "ping localhost" after taskkill. Or maybe use a plugin to kill processes: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category:Plugins

Comment: I used KillProcDLL::KillProc and its worked! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling directly to taskkill?

```
Execwait '"$SYSDIR\taskkill.exe" /F /IM chrome.exe /T'
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly:

```
Chrome --> downloaded_setup.exe --> install.exe --> force kill chrome w/ child processes
```

So to answer to you question: no there is no mean to make the setup started by Chrome resist to a force kill (it is actually killed because of the `/T` parameter that kills the whole process subtree with child processes). You are just cutting the branch you are standing in :)

If you do need to kill Chrome, I would suggest to try to spawn a second copy of `downloaded_setup.exe` from itself but detached from calling process (see [CreateProcess flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

In the second instance of the setup, you can check if you are the second process by testing its parent (process name of parent pid would be chrome or not) with the [get process info macros](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Get_process_info).

---

**EDIT:** i wrongly interpreted the meaning of the `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag for `CreateProcess`: its usage is for console programs, to not make them use the console inherited by their parent.

Actually, to make a process detached from its parent A, the only way is to start a process B that will start a process C and quit the process B. Then the process C is no more descendant of A and if you kill A, C will stay alive.

For the fun of proff of concept, here is a NSIS script that will respawn itself if started by Chrome. If you look at the processes with ProcessExplorer or ProcessHacker when the messagebox shows, you will see that the visible setup is not child of chrome... Thanks to Anders that helped me to debug the call to `CreateProcess` :)

```
!include "TextFunc.nsh"
!include "logiclib.nsh"
!include "getprocessinfo.nsh"
outfile "parent.exe"

!define DEBUG `System::Call kernel32::OutputDebugString(ts)`

!define PARENT "chrome.exe"
Var cmd

Section
    ; Do your stuff here
    ; ...
SectionEnd

Function .onInit
    ${GetProcessInfo} 0 $0 $1 $2 $3 $4  ;info for current process pid
    ${GetProcessInfo} $1 $0 $1 $2 $3 $5 ;get parent process info

 ${if} $3 == ${PARENT}
    StrCpy $cmd '"$EXEDIR\$EXEFILE"'
    System::Alloc 68            ;// $1 = buffer for struct STARTUPINFO
    Pop $1
    System::Call "*$1(i 68)"    ;// StartUp.cb=sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    System::Alloc 16            ;// $2 = buffer for struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    Pop $2

    System::Call 'kernel32::CreateProcess(i0,t $cmd,i0,i0,i0,i0,i0,i0,ir1,ir2)i.r0' ;re-spawn ourselve
    System::Free $1
    ${if} $0 <> 0
        System::Call "*$2(i.r3,i.r4,i.r5,i.r6) ?!e"
        ;${debug} "PHND=$3 PID=$5"
        System::Call 'kernel32::CloseHandle(i $3)'
        System::Call 'kernel32::CloseHandle(i $4)'
    ${endif}
    System::Free $2
    Quit
 ${endif}
    Sleep 500   ;wait to have time for parent process to quit
    MessageBox MB_OK "My parent is not ${PARENT}"
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Is there an nsis script example out there? its seems difficult .. for how creating a new process that is detached from chrome tree.. ?

Comment: I searched and can't find anything that suggest how to create a detached process from the setup.exe.  I will very appreciate it if you can set me a direction in order to solve this problem, thank you!

Comment: while the question is answered, for the fun I made a proof of concept of how to create a detached process with NSIS. See my edit.