# calling CreateProcess via system plugin

Tags: winapi, mingw, nsis

I did not managed to call successfully `CreateProcess()` from an installer.

While the following C code (compiled with MinGW on Win7) can start `notepad.exe` with no problem:

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    BOOL result;
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;

    memset(&startupInfo,0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
    memset(&processInformation, 0, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    //these 2 values are used for NSIS
    printf("sizeof(startupInfo) = %d\n",sizeof(startupInfo));
    printf("sizeof(processInformation) = %d\n",sizeof(processInformation));

    result = CreateProcess(NULL, "NOTEPAD.exe", 
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          FALSE,
                          0,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          &startupInfo,
                          &processInformation
                        );
    if(result == 0)
        printf("Could not create process, lasterr =  %ld\n", GetLastError());

}
```

This equivalent NSIS script fails horribly on both WinXp and Win7:

```
!include "TextFunc.nsh"
!include "logiclib.nsh"
outfile "process.exe"

!define DEBUG `System::Call kernel32::OutputDebugString(ts)`
Var cmd

Section

StrCpy $cmd "notepad.exe"
;System::Alloc 72           ;// $1 = struct STARTUPINFO
;Pop $1
System::Call "*(i 68, i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, &i2 0, &i2 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0) p.r1"        ;// StartUp.cb=sizeof(StartUp);

;System::Alloc 16           ;// $2 = struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
;Pop $2
System::Call "*(i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0) p.r2"

;System::Call "*$1(i 68)"       ;// StartUp.cb=sizeof(StartUp);
System::Call /NOUNLOAD 'kernel32::CreateProcess(i 0, t $cmd, i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, i r1, i.r2)i.r0 ?e'
Pop $9
${debug} "$0 lasterr=$9"
StrCmp $0 "0" 0 Good
MessageBox MB_OK "CreateProcess failed"
${debug} "CreateProcess failed"
Goto Free
Good:
${debug} "get infos"
System::Call "*$2(i.r3,i.r4,i.r5,i.r6) ?!e"
${debug} "PHND=$3 PID=$5"
System::Call 'kernel32::CloseHandle(i $3)'
System::Call 'kernel32::CloseHandle(i $4)'
Free:
System::Free $1
System::Free $2

SectionEnd
```

When I replace the `System::Cal` for structure allocation and use `System::Alloc` instead, there is no crash but `CreateProcess` fails and `GetLastError` returns 87 (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`)

What am I missing for fixing that `CreateProcess`? I do not want to use builtin `Exec` because I wanted to play with `CreateProcess` flags that are not accessible from nsis script.

**Edit:** I get my error : in the call to `CreateProcess` the last argument `i.r2` must be `ir2` : the memory block for `PROCESS_INFORMATION` is already allocated and its pointer must be passed to `CreateProcess`, while the `i.r2` is ignoring the value before the call and only takes it after. Thanks to Anders for his help :)

Comment: Allocating 72 and setting the size to 68 does not make much sense, there is probably some padding in the struct after the WORDs...

Comment: well, the 72 / 68 come from the many tests i have done before asking SO. I only found 2 usages of system plugin + create process: in [nsis wiki](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecWait_and_waiting_for_child_processes_with_Job_Objects) and in [another forum](http://portableapps.com/node/12561#comment-76796) and I eventually used 68 - the value that is returned by `sizeof()` in my C test code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p` is not a valid type if you are using NSIS 2.46 and I believe you got the size wrong for STARTUPINFO.

```
Section 
System::Call '*(i,i,i,i)i.r0'
System::Alloc 72
pop $4
System::Call "*$4(i 72)"
StrCpy $1 '"explorer.exe" "$startmenu"'
System::Call 'kernel32::CreateProcess(i0,tr1,i0,i0,i0,i 0,i0,i0,ir4,ir0)i.r3'
DetailPrint RET=$3
System::Free $4
${If} $3 <> 0
    System::Call "*$0(i.r3,i.r4)"
    System::Call 'kernel32::CloseHandle(i $3)'
    System::Call 'kernel32::CloseHandle(i $4)'
${EndIf}
System::Free $0
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Oh? I do use the 2.46 source (locally compiled to activate 8192 string size and verbose installation log) Well `p` is from the system plugin  online reference, while my local fil misses it. The boths docs have the same date, though. And my 68 value come from the `printf(sizeof())` in my C code...

Comment: I remember why 68 instead of 72 : the `STARTUPINFO` has 18 members; if you allocate 18 x 4 bytes like for 18 `DWORD` you get 72 bytes, but actually 2 members are `WORD` thus making 4 less bytes

Comment: Well, the code I posted worked when I tried it, if it breaks when you use 68 you know what the problem is, if not then the code on the wiki is wrong...

Comment: I got it: I passed a wrong `i.r2` for the last parameter to `CreateProcess`, ignoring the buffer address I allocated. Thanks!

Comment: I posted a full use case with a value of 68 that is working well for [that other weird question question regarding process killing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13933469/317266)